# Custom Facebook author tag wordpress

Tags: facebook, tags

I have a function in Wordpress that checks if the user of the post haves a Facebook id then add the specific meta tag with this Facebook id else if is empty then it's adding the preset Facebook id. The problem is that if the user of the post haves an Facebook id in the facebookurl area the function is only adding the default Facebook id.

```html
function facebook_author_tag() {
  if ( is_single() ) {
    global $post;
    $author = (int) $post->post_author;
    $facebook_url = the_author_meta('facebook_url');
     if ( !empty( $facebook_url ) )
  { 
     echo '<meta property="article:author" content="'. $facebook_url .'" />';
  } else{
    echo '<meta property="article:author" content="https://www.facebook.com/test" />';
     }
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'facebook_author_tag', 8 );
```

And this code I used to insert the socials fields in the user's page.

```html
function my_new_contactmethods( $contactmethods ) {
// Add Twitter
$contactmethods['twitter'] = 'Twitter';
//add Facebook
$contactmethods['facebook'] = 'Facebook';


 
return $contactmethods;
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods','my_new_contactmethods',10,1);
```

Thanks if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone have this issue this was the working code:

```
function facebook_author_tag() {
if ( is_single() ) {
    global $post;
    $author = (int) $post->post_author;
    $facebook_url = get_the_author_meta( 'facebook_url', $author );
if (empty( $facebook_url ) ) {
    echo '<meta property="article:author"     content="https://www.facebook.com/test/"/><meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/test/" />';

    }
else{ 
    echo '<meta property="article:author" content="'. $facebook_url .'" /><meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/test/" />';

    }
  }
}
```